# ¿Cómo hacer una función en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, funciones, tablas

Tengo un pequeño ejercicio de funciones a ver si me pueden ayudar:

Con las siguientes tablas:
-Prestamo(id, nombre, fecha)
-Pagos(idPago,IdPrestamo,monto,fecha)

Crear una función que busque la suma de los pagos de cada préstamo. 
Luego crear una consulta que permita listar los prestamos con el total pagado, calculado con esa función. Considera solo los pagos de menos de dos años.

Comment: Parece un duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/338728/sql-server-funciones-para-sumar?noredirect=1#comment614349_338728 trata de seguir la recomendación que ya me di

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822